# What is client context and role assignments?

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

This script is used to remove all sharing link on files.
My question is: I don't understand what `Get-PnPContext` is or what `RoleAssignment` is?

I don't understand those commands, can someone explain them to me?

```
param (   
       $OneDriveURL
   )   
process{

    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $OneDriveURL 
    $Ctx= Get-PnPContext


    $Files= Get-PnPListItem -List "documents"
    foreach( $File in $Files)
      {       
            $Froles= $File.RoleAssignments
            $Ctx.load($Froles)
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            If($Froles.Count -gt 0)
            {

              for ($i = $Froles.Count -1; $i -ge 0 ; --$i)  
               {   
                  $Link=$Froles[$i].Member
                  $Ctx.Load($Link)
                  $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
                  If($Link.title -like "SharingLinks*")
                  {
                   $Froles[$i].DeleteObject()
                  }
                  $Link = $null
               }  
              $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()           
             }      
      }

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you can get a lot of information on all PowerShell commands by using the `Get-Help` (or simply the alias `help`) before the command itself:

```
> help Get-PnPClientContext
DESCRIPTION
  Returns a Client Side Object Model context
```

In that case, not very helpful unless you know what the [ClientContext Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee538685(v%3Doffice.15)) actually does. Simply explained, the client context is an object that contains information about SharePoint objects (*sites, lists and items*) and methods (*create, read, update, delete*).

We need it to be able to do things like retrieve files and send updates back.

---

An item can have many [Role Assignments](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/authorization-users-groups-and-the-object-model-in-sharepoint#high-level-view-of-object-relationsscopes-users-groups-and-roles). Each of them contains a user or a group as well as role definitions that says what the user or group is allowed to do with that item.

In your script, you are looping through the role assignments of each item and looking for members (users/groups) that begin with "SharingLinks". These are special SharePoint groups that are created when you use the Share/Get link function of a library.

When you delete just these members from the role assignments, you are removing all the sharing links but leaving the rest of the permissions set for the files intact.

Answer (score 0):

**What is Get-PnPContext?**

It returns a Client Side Object Model context.

For example,

```
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
```

The above code will put the current context in the $ctx variable.

For details about the Get-PnPContext refer to the below MSDN article:

[Get-PnPContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpcontext?view=sharepoint-ps)

**What is RoleAssignment?**

It defines the securable object role assignments for a user or group on the Web site, list, or list item.

Otherway, we can say a role assignment is a relationship between role definitions, users and groups, and scopes.

**Is there any impact on SharePoint over a larger number of role assignments?**

A large number of role assignments will lead to **performance degradation**.  When a user accesses an item, such as a site, page, list, library, or item, role assignments have to be checked to determine permission.  If the role assignments list is huge, this will impact the amount of time it takes to figure out the user’s permissions.  Other operations such as viewing list/library permissions, granting/revoking permissions, and removing users from site collections will also suffer.

For example, on our troubled site collection with over 5 million role assignments, it could take up to 2 hours to remove a user from the site collection.  Once role assignments were cleaned up, removal time decreased to about 10 seconds.

Source:

[SharePoint Role Assignments](https://www.thelazyspadmin.com/sharepoint-role-assignments/)

For more details on RoleAssignment refer to the below MSDN article:

[RoleAssignment class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee546224%28v%3Doffice.15%29)

[RoleAssignment properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536418(v%3Doffice.15))